# Probability of independent, mutually non-exclusive, binary events

Tags: probability

We have three binary events which can succeed or fail: $A$, $B$ and $C$.

The probability of success for each event of $A$, $B$ and $C$ is $0.9$.

The events $A,B$ and $C$ are independent of each other and mutually non-exclusive.

What is the probability that exactly 1 event succeeds?

a. Which formula should I use?
\begin{align}
P(X) &= {n \choose r}\cdot P(\text{Success})^r \cdot P(\text{Failure})^{n-r} \tag1 \\
P(A \text{ or } B \text{ or } C) &= P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(AB)-P(AC)-P(BC)+P(ABC) \tag2
\end{align}
b. Why does the second formula give negative result? Why doesn't it work in this case?

Comment: For the second formula, it should be a plus sign for the $P(ABC)$ part, not a minus sign.

Comment: You want the existence of a successful event, or exactly one event succeed?  Formula (1) accounts for the later; formula (2) calculates the former.

Comment: @GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會  - Thank you for the clarification! I want the probability of exactly one event succeeds. Just to proof if I understand correctly: (1) expresses the probability that 1 event from the 3 succeeds while the other 2 fails and (2) expresses the probability that exactly 1 from the three events succeeds while the other two can succeed or fail?

Comment: @Geri If you want to use a distribution you should use the [Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) rather then the Binomial distribution.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189) I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\rm \LaTeX$](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see
e.g. 
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305).

Comment: @callculus That's no need to ping the post owner by `@OP` because he/she will be notified in any case.

Comment: @GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會thank you very much for your edits!

Comment: @callculus - thank you for your comment

Comment: @Minus One-Twelfth - thank you for the correction

Comment: @Geri Are you fine now? Any further questions?

Comment: I think you can edit the question to clarify what you mean by "1 event succeeds".

Comment: @callculus: do I understand correctly that (1) expresses the probability that 1 event from the 3 succeeds while the other 2 fails and (2) expresses the probability that exactly 1 from the three events succeeds while the other two can succeed or fail?

Comment: @GNUSupporter 8964民主女神 地下教會 - You can understand success in the context of a binary event. I corrected the description.

Comment: @Geri The problem is that the binomial distribution (1) cannot be used in case of 3 events. So your question makes no sense.

Comment: @callculus - I see. Thank you for the clarification. I understand now.

Comment: @Geri Do you want the probability that $\textrm{exactly}$ one event succeeds or that $\textrm{at least}$ one of the three events succeeds?

Comment: @callculus - I want the probability of exactly one event succeeds

Comment: @Geri You have to know, for instance, the value of $P(A\cap B)$ to calculate it. In you case it is not zero, since the events are not mutually exclusive.